# Method Overloading in java - using List Type

Tags: java, overloading

```
class Value {
    public void method1(List<Integer> intList) {

    }

    public void method1(List<Double> doubleList) {

    }

}
```

Not able to use function overloading in the above two methods.
This looks like both the methods are taking `List` as a parameter.
Is there a way to differentiate the parameters on the data type of Lists?

This is the error message:

```
Erasure of method method1(List<Integer>) is the same as another method in type Value
```

Is there any other way through which I can use overloading here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use generics for this:

```
public void method1(List<?> list) {

}
```

---

Declaring method in this way, you can check the content of the list and do the job you need:

```
public static void check(List<?> list) {
    // check null
    if (Objects.equals(null, list)) 
        System.out.println("null");
    // check empty
    else if (list.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("empty");
    // if the list is ok, let's see what it has inside
    else if (list.get(0) instanceof Integer)
        System.out.println("int");
    else if (list.get(0) instanceof Double)
        System.out.println("double");
}
```

Simple main for execution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<Double>(); 
    check(null);
    check(ints);
    ints.add(1);
    check(ints);
    doubles.add(1D);
    check(doubles);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
null
empty
int
double
```

[**WORKING IDEONE DEMO**](https://ideone.com/hA3tSc)

Comment: How would it hepl if two methods must do different actions?

Comment: @SergheyBishyr please check my edit :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare more than one method with the same name and the same number and type of arguments, because the compiler cannot tell them apart. See [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could have `method1(List<Object> List)` and check the type in the method with `instanceof`

Comment: that won't work. you can't detect the difference between a `List<Integer>` and a `List<Double>` at runtime

Comment: isnt it possible by doing something like :     if List[0] instnaceof Integer ?

Comment: sure, but that's very unreliable. what if it's a mixed list with Integers and Doubles? what if it's an empty list?

Comment: True true, it would imply a lot of checks before. my bad